# If I add anything to an If statement nothing works

Tags: javascript, html, forms, if-statement

Working on a very basic available space calculator for work. People enter in the dimensions for the room, aisle and stage widths, etc and it should return how many sections of how many square feet are available. Not a big JavaScript programmer but everything seems to look right. I have been using the W3 Schools compiler to quickly see changes as I make them but when I put anything inside the final If Else statement the compiler just outputs "Error" and if opened in  a browser the Submit button does nothing.

```
function calculate() {
    "use strict";
    var finalLength, finalWidth, sections, finalSquare, sectionsSize, room;
    room = document.getElementById('room');
    finalLength = room.length.value - room.depth.value - room.backstage.value - room.front.value;
    finalWidth = room.width.value - room.side.value - (room.centerCount.value * room.center.value);
    sections = 1 + room.centerCount.value;
    finalSquare = finalLength * finalWidth;
    sectionsSize = finalSquare / sections;

    if (sections == '1') {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Your room is " + finalSquare + " square feet.";
    } else if (sections == '2' || sections == '3' || sections == '4') {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Your room is going to have " + sections + " sections that are " + sectionsSize + " square feet.";
    }
}
```

Here is the form the function is pulling its information from:

```
<form id="room">
    Length of Room(Front to Back): <input type="text" name="roomLength" id="length"/><br/>
    Width of Room: <input type="text" name="roomWidth" id="width"/><br/>
    Depth of Stage: <input type="text" name="stageDepth" id="depth"/><br/>
    Depth of Backstage: <input type="text" name="backstageDepth" id="backstage"/><br/>
    Space between stage and first row: <input type="text" name="frontWalk" id="front"/><br/>
    Width of Side Aisle: <select name="sideIsles" id="side">
        <option value=6 selected>3</option>
        <option value=8>4</option>
        <option value=10>5</option>
    </select><br/>
    How many Center Aisle: <select name="centerIsleCount" id="centerCount" onchange='centerExists(this.value);'>
        <option value="0" selected>0</option>
        <option value=1>1</option>
        <option value=2>2</option>
        <option value=3>3</option>
    </select><br/>
    <div id="centerExists" style='display:none;'>
        Width of Center Aisle: <select name="centerIsle" id="center">
            <option value=4 selected>4</option>
            <option value=5>5</option>
            <option value=6>6</option>
        </select><br/>
    </div>
    <p id="demo">Please enter the above information.</p>
    <button type="button" onclick="calculate()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The part that is not working is this if statement:

```
if (sections == '1') {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Your room is " + finalSquare + " square feet.";
} else if (sections == '2' || sections == '3' || sections == '4') {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Your room is going to have " + sections + " sections that are " + sectionsSize + " square feet.";
}
```

Here is the script for centerExists. It is right under the caclulate() in the head:

```
function centerExists(val) {
    "use strict";
    var element = document.getElementById('centerExists');
    if (val !== '0') {
        element.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        element.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to add to the code that doesn't work?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you would neatly indent both your JS and HTML code.

Comment: Where's the code for `centerExists` in `onchange='centerExists(this.value);'`

Comment: You can make a working demo using jsfiddle.net. It's better than using w3 schools as you can share a link to your issues. Also learn to use your browsers developer tool bar. Hit f12 in Chrome,Firefox,IE and you will get a console with *slightly* better error messages. You don't compile JS it's interpreted, so work on your local host with said browser of choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a number plus a string results in something different than what you expect.

```
sections = 1 + room.centerCount.value;
```

if the value is zero, it is equal to `"10"`

Use

```
sections = 1 + parseInt(room.centerCount.value, 10);
```

and in your if/else if, you need to compare to numbers.

Comment: Strings also could be converted to numbers via "+", `sections = 1 + +room.centerCount.value;` works fine too. Just another way to solve the issue :)